# How do I convert RichTextBox's Flow Document to HTML?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I convert RichTextBox's Flow Document to HTML? I need to send data like 
`<p>ehf ihiwef weoi</p>` to the server.

I need a good and easy solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Though It looks too hard I have one solution for this. First, download this solution
[MarkupConverter](https://github.com/mmanela/MarkupConverter)

Then add the class library (MarkupConverter) to your solution or project.
Boom!! You are done. Now just call the methods to convert like this...........

```
private IMarkupConverter markupConverter;

public PersonalDetailsEditPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Current = this;
            markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
            DataContext = this;
        }

 public void Populate_Data(UserModel userModel)
        {
            doc = AddressTextBox.Document;
            htmlStr_address = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(FlowDocument_GetText(doc));
        }
```

**Note:** AddressTextBox is not a TextBox but a RichTextBox. I just named like this. And I am sorry for that.